# как из state удалить значение? react js

Tags: reactjs

есть функция deleteHandler, он принимает параметр index  и хочу чтобы из state удалился значение ,как это сделать ?

import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import './App.css';
    import List from './List/List'

```
class App extends Component {

  state = {
    cars: [
      {name: 'Ford'},
      {name: 'Audi'},
      {name: 'Mazda'}
    ]
  }

  deleteHandler(index) {
    console.log(index);
  }

  render() {
    const divStyle = {
      textAlign: 'center'
    }

    return (
      <div style={divStyle}>

        { this.state.cars.map((car, index) => {
          return (
            <List
              key = {index}
              name = {car.name}
              onDelete = {this.deleteHandler.bind(this, index)}
            />
          )
        }) }
        <input type="text" />
        <button>Add</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте следующий вариант:

```
 deleteHandler(index) {
    const { cars } = this.state;
    const newCars = cars.filter((car, idx) => idx !== index);
    this.setState({ cars: newCars });
 }
```

Во второй строке функции мы создаем новый массив машин путём фильтрации текущего массива, оставляя только те машины, индекс которых не равен аргументу `deleteHandler`. 
Например, если мы хотим удалить машину с индексом 2. Метод `filter` вернёт новый массив, в котором будут только те элементы массива `cars`, у которых индекс не равен двойке (`idx !== index`).

Подробнее про метод массива `filter` можно почитать [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: работает , можете объяснить что тут написано 

const newCars = cars.filter((car, idx) => idx !== index);

Comment: @SabaKoghuashvili да, конечно. Сейчас добавлю описание к ответу.

Comment: все понятно , спасибо

Comment: можно укоротить - this.setState(prevState => ({cars: prevState.cars.filter((car, i) => i !== index});

Comment: можно еще короче: this.setState(p => ({ cars: p.cars.filter((c, i) => i !== index)});

Comment: да, можно всю функцию в 1 строку написать даже, const deleteHandler = (index) => this.setState(p => ({ cars: p.cars.filter((c, i) => i !== index)});